# Integrating $\int\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{1+x+x^2}\right)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{1+x+x^2}\right)\,dx $$

How to evaluate the above integral?

In my school life I learnt how to evaluate
$$\arctan\frac1{1+x+x^2}$$ To evaluate this, we used to take $x$ common from the denominator. The denominator used to become $1+{x(1+x)}$. Then after this we used to write the numerator as $(1+x)-(x)$. So finally the integrand will become
$$\arctan\left(\frac{(1+x)-x}{1+{(1+x)(x)}}\right)$$ So finally the integrand is of the form of
$$\arctan\dfrac{b-a}{1+ab}$$
where $b=(1+x)$ and $a=x$. So, now we used to integrate by integrating $\arctan(1+x)-\arctan(x)$ separately.

But how to integrate $\arcsin\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2}$?

Please help me out.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your post so that it is readable:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This problem is a monster : there is a solution in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: How to solve the integrand?

Comment: [The answer doesn't look pretty, unfortunately.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arcsin%281%2F%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%29+integral)

Comment: As Claude said, the calculation linked by @Accelerator provides our answer in terms of the elliptic integral $\Pi$.

Comment: The only reason you were able to integrate $\arctan\left(\frac 1{1+x+x^2}\right)$ nicely is because of the identity relating $\arctan(1+x)$ and $\arctan x$ to $\arctan\left(\frac 1{1+x+x^2}\right)$. Unless such a relation exists for $\arcsin$, it is highly unlikely you are going to get a "nice" function for its integral